# How can I remove "Set" from table name, when I generate database from Entity framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

How can I remove "Set" from table name, when I generate database from Entity framework 6?

For example, I have created entity with name "Articles". When I generate database from Entity Framework Model, it creates articles table with "ArticlesSet" name.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *.toTable()* method, like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DefaultName>().ToTable("CustomName");
```

Sample:

```
public class MyEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public const string TableName = "CustomName";

    public ActionMap()
    {                   
        ToTable(TableName);

        Property(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).

Or, you can also try the Table annotation:

```
[Table("CustomName")]
public class DefaultName
```

Comment: But I need to do this for each table :-( Does exists any possibility of generate table name from "Name" of entity and not from the "Entity Set Name"?

Comment: I don't think so, or, at least, I don't know how to do it. Anyway, it's an operation you do only once... or not?

Comment: I always would like to create database model from Entity Framework. Therefore, I would like to found the best solution. I think, remove "Set" from "Entity Set Name" is bad practice.